# How do you get the page to jump down from a link in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is my site http://web.njit.edu/~dp257/boilerplate/Org.html 
i am trying this just for "World Wide web" since it is at the bottom and when i click it, it deletes the rest of the page except for that definition, my head is hurting trying to fix this.  Click the world wide web link on the side bar to see what it does.

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <header id="name" align="center">IS117 TERMS</header>
         <div id="primary_links" align="center">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="website.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="CSS.html">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="HTML.html">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="Org.html">Organizations</a></li>
                <li><a href="Tech.html">Technologies</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>

            <div id="content">
                <h1>Organizations</h1>

        <p>
            Client- the computers and devices that use web applications
        </p>
        <p>
            Internet exchange point-a point in the world that connect many WAN’s 
        </p>
        <p>
            Internet- global system of interconnected networks
        </p>
        <p>
        Internet service provider- Someone or company who owns a WAN and leases its access to their network
        </p>
        <p>
            Intranet- network where only employees can run web applications typically they are in the same area
        </p>
        <p>
            Local area network- a small network of computers that are near each other and communicate over short distances
        </p>
        <p>
            Network-a system that allows clients and servers to communicate
        </p>
        <p>
            W3C-world wide web consortium, group that develops standards, for code
        </p>
        <p>
            Web browser-programs that access web pages
        </p>
        <p>
            Web server- holds the files that make up a web application
        </p>

        <p>
            WHATWG-community of people interested in evolving html, big source of info
        </p>
        <p>
            Wide area network-2 or more LAN’s connected by a router
        </p>

        <p id = "p5">
             World wide web-components that bring together a web page to your desktop over the internet
        </p>



        </div> <!-- content -->


    <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="secondary_links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Client</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Internet Exchange Point</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Internet Service Provide</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intranet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Local Area Network</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Network</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">W3C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Browser</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Server</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WHATWG</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wide Area Network</a></li>
            <li><a href="#p5">World Wide Web</a></li>               
        </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Um..it doesn't do anything? it links to just the hash tag.

Comment: i change the href to "#h1" in the firebug and click on the link it works in the site you povided with url http://web.njit.edu/~dp257/boilerplate/Org.html#h1

Comment: The page you linked to doesn't do anything on click, but the code in the question actually does specify `<a href="#p5">` and that should work. Can you be clearer about what the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

There is no paragraph with ID `p5`. Simply add the ID of `p5` to the fifth paragraph (or whichever one you want the page to go to). There is no need for an anchor or another added element

```
<p id='p5'>
    Intranet- network where only employees can run web applications ...
</p>
```

`href`s need to point to URLs. In the case of navigating to a new section of a page, they require an ID instead, which then affects the URL

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHzK8/)